# How to show a different form on click of a radio button in HTML by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code. I want to display the login form on click of the login radio button and similarly signup form for sign up radio button.

I am getting an error

_blank.html:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
at loginUser
at HTMLInputElement.onclick

_blank.html:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
at signupUser
at HTMLInputElement.onclick

```js
function loginUser(logindiv){
            console.log('login');
            var newdivlogin = document.createElement('div');
            newdivlogin.innerHTML = "<label>SignUp</label><br/>"+"<input placeholder='email'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='password'/><br/>";
            document.getElementById(logindiv).append(newdivlogin);
        }
    
        function signupUser(signupdiv){
            console.log('signup');
            var newdivsignup = document.createElement('div');
            newdivsignup.innerHTML = "<label>SignUp</label><br/>"+"<input placeholder='email'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='password'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='name'/><br/>";
            document.getElementById(signupdiv).append(newdivsignup);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Links</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="user">
          <h1>Please Login or Sign up if you are new User</h1>
          <input type="radio" id="login" name="radio" onclick="loginUser('user');" /><label>Login</label>
          <input type="radio" id="signup" name="radio" onclick="signupUser('user');" /><label>Sign Up</label><br/>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It appears to me that you are passing in 'user' which is a class name (<div class="user">), not an ID. But in function loginUser(logindiv) and function signupUser(signupdiv) you are calling document.getElementById(), which expects an id name not a class name. You might want document.getElementsByClassName(). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Change `class="user"` to `id="user"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Links</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="user">
        <h1>Please Login or Sign up if you are new User</h1>
        <input type="radio" id="login" name="radio" onclick="loginUser('user');" /><label>Login</label>
        <input type="radio" id="signup" name="radio" onclick="signupUser('user');" /><label>Sign Up</label><br/>
    </div>

    <script>
        function loginUser(logindiv){
            console.log('login');
            var newdivlogin = document.createElement('div');
            newdivlogin.innerHTML = "<label>LogIn</label><br/>"+"<input placeholder='email'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='password'/><br/>";
            document.getElementById(logindiv).append(newdivlogin);
        }
    
        function signupUser(signupdiv){
            console.log('signup');
            var newdivsignup = document.createElement('div');
            newdivsignup.innerHTML = "<label>SignUp</label><br/>"+"<input placeholder='email'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='password'/><br/>"+"<input placeholder='name'/><br/>";
            document.getElementById(signupdiv).append(newdivsignup);
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<div class="user">` change to `<div id="user">`